# How do i start the turn by turn NavigationLauncher from another activity

Tags: android, mapbox

I am trying to launch the `NavigationLauncher.startNavigation`, from another activity but am unable to do so. I have a button in the second activity which I want to use to start the navigation.
Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Here is my code:

```
/* 
fabstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        boolean simulateRoute = false;
        NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
            .directionsRoute(route)
            .shouldSimulateRoute(simulateRoute)
            .build();
        // Call this method with Context from within an Activity
        NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(MainActivity.this, options);

    }
});
*/
fabstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Before_Go.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        // Here is where I want to go to a new activity, inside this activity have a button to
        // launch the "NavigationLauncher.startNavigation"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

NavigationLauncher.startnavigation() opens a new activity that handles the navigation. Therefore it does not matter from where it is called. However, wherever it is called from, the NavigationLauncher must be defined, and the options object that is passed as the second parameter has to contain the directionsRoute object.

Can you please share code of the activity from which you call it, as well as how you initialize and define the options object?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your response to my question. I am new to stakoverflow, so i hope i get this additional posting of code right.

```
MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, PermissionsListener,
        MapboxMap.OnMapLongClickListener, OnRouteSelectionChangeListener {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE = 1;
    private static final int ONE_HUNDRED_MILLISECONDS = 100;
    //private static final String DROPPED_MARKER_LAYER_ID = "DROPPED_MARKER_LAYER_ID";

    //Mapbox
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapboxMap mapboxMap;
    private LocationComponent locationComponent;
    private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
    private LocationEngine locationEngine;
    private long DEFAULT_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000L;
    private long DEFAULT_MAX_WAIT_TIME = DEFAULT_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS * 5;
    private final MainActivityLocationCallback callback = new MainActivityLocationCallback(this);
    private NavigationMapRoute mapRoute;
    private DirectionsRoute route;

    private String symbolIconId = "symbolIconId";
    private String geojsonSourceLayerId = "geojsonSourceLayerId";
    private StyleCycle styleCycle = new StyleCycle();
    CarmenFeature selectedCarmenFeature;
    CarmenFeature feature;
    Layer layer;

    private static final String TAG = "DirectionsActivity";

  

    // variables
    private FloatingActionButton fablocation;
    private FloatingActionButton fabstart;
    private FloatingActionButton fabRemoveRoute;
    private FloatingActionButton fabStyles;
    private TextView search;
    private TextView kmDisplay;
    private TextView timeDisplay;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token));

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);

        search=findViewById(R.id.search);
        kmDisplay = findViewById(R.id.kmDisplay);
        timeDisplay = findViewById(R.id.timeDisplay);
        fablocation=findViewById(R.id.fabLocation);
        fabstart=findViewById(R.id.fabStart);
        fabRemoveRoute=findViewById(R.id.fabRemoveRoute);
        fabStyles=findViewById(R.id.fabStyles);

        fablocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Location lastKnownLocation = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent().getLastKnownLocation();

                // Move map camera back to current device location
                mapboxMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(
                        new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                .target(new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude()))
                                .zoom(15)
                                .build()), 3000);

            }
        });


    }



    @Override
    public boolean onMapLongClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {
        vibrate();


        Point destinationPoint = Point.fromLngLat(point.getLongitude(), point.getLatitude());
        Point originPoint = Point.fromLngLat(locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation().getLongitude(),
                locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation().getLatitude());

        GeoJsonSource source = mapboxMap.getStyle().getSourceAs("destination-source-id");
        if (source != null) {
            source.setGeoJson(Feature.fromGeometry(destinationPoint));
        } else {

            // Use the map camera target's coordinates to make a reverse geocoding search
            reverseGeocode(Point.fromLngLat(point.getLongitude(), point.getLatitude()));
        }

        getRoute(originPoint, destinationPoint);

        if(destinationPoint !=originPoint) {

            

            fabRemoveRoute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    removeRouteAndMarkers();
                    fabstart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    fabRemoveRoute.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    //fablocation.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    kmDisplay.setText("");
                    timeDisplay.setText("");
                    search.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.hint_where_to)));


                    Location lastKnownLocation = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent().getLastKnownLocation();

                    // Move map camera back to current device location
                    mapboxMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(
                            new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                    .target(new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude()))
                                    .zoom(15)
                                    .build()), 3000);
                }
            });


        }
        //imageView.setEnabled(true);
        //imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.mapboxBlue);

        return true;
    }

    private void getRoute(Point origin, Point destination) {
        NavigationRoute.builder(this)
                .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
                .origin(origin)
                .destination(destination)
                .voiceUnits(DirectionsCriteria.METRIC)
                .alternatives(true)
                .build()
                .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
                    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {
// You can get the generic HTTP info about the response
                        if (response.isSuccessful()
                                && response.body() != null
                                && !response.body().routes().isEmpty()) {
                            List<DirectionsRoute> routes = response.body().routes();
                            mapRoute.addRoutes(routes);
                            //routeLoading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            fabRemoveRoute.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            fablocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            fabstart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            route = response.body().routes().get(0);

                            routeCalcs();
   
                        }

                        // Once you have the route zoom the camera out to show the route within the bounds of the device
                        mapboxMap.easeCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(
                                new LatLngBounds.Builder()
                                        .include(new LatLng(origin.latitude(), origin.longitude()))
                                        .include(new LatLng(destination.latitude(), destination.longitude()))
                                        .build(), 150), 4000);

                  }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + throwable.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }

    private void removeRouteAndMarkers() {
        mapRoute.removeRoute();
        toggleLayer();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNewPrimaryRouteSelected(DirectionsRoute directionsRoute) {

        route = directionsRoute;
        routeCalcs();
    }



    private void routeCalcs(){

        // rounds the kilometer to zero decimals
        kmDisplay.setText((int) Math.ceil(route.distance()/1000) + " km");
        //Log.d(TAG1,(int) Math.ceil(currentRoute.distance()/1000) + " km");


        // This converts to output of duration() in seconds to minutes and hours format
        int minutes = (int) (route.duration() / 60);
          
        long hour = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toHours(minutes);
        long remainMinute = minutes - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hour);

        if (hour >= 1) {

            timeDisplay.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.hours_textview),hour)
                    + String.format(getString(R.string.minutes_textview),remainMinute));


        } else {

            timeDisplay.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.minutes_textview), remainMinute));

        }
    }


    private void reverseGeocode(Point point) {

        if (selectedCarmenFeature == null) {

            try {
                MapboxGeocoding client = MapboxGeocoding.builder()
                        .accessToken(getString(R.string.access_token))
                        .query(Point.fromLngLat(point.longitude(), point.latitude()))
                        .geocodingTypes(GeocodingCriteria.TYPE_ADDRESS)
                        .build();

                client.enqueueCall(new Callback<GeocodingResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<GeocodingResponse> call, Response<GeocodingResponse> response) {

                        if (response.body() != null) {
                            List<CarmenFeature> results = response.body().features();
                            if (results.size() > 0) {
                                feature = results.get(0);

// If the geocoder returns a result, we take the first in the list and show a Toast with the place name.
                                mapboxMap.getStyle(new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                                        if (style.getLayer("SYMBOL_LAYER_ID") != null) {
                       
                                            search.setText(feature.placeName());
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                        getString(R.string.location_picker_dropped_marker_snippet_no_results), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<GeocodingResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
                        Timber.e("Geocoding Failure: %s", throwable.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            } catch (ServicesException servicesException) {
                Timber.e("Error geocoding: %s", servicesException.toString());
                servicesException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;

        mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS, new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {

            @Override
            public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style){
                mapRoute = new NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView, mapboxMap);
                mapRoute.setOnRouteSelectionChangeListener(MainActivity.this::onNewPrimaryRouteSelected);
                mapboxMap.addOnMapLongClickListener(MainActivity.this);
                initializeLocationComponent(style);


                // Add the symbol layer icon to map for future use
                style.addImage(symbolIconId, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        MainActivity.this.getResources(), R.drawable.mapbox_marker_icon_default));

                // Create an empty GeoJSON source using the empty feature collection
                setUpSource(style);

                // Set up a new symbol layer for displaying the searched location's feature coordinates
                setupLayer(style);

                fabStyles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (mapboxMap != null) {
                            mapboxMap.setStyle(styleCycle.getNextStyle());


                        }
                    }
                });

                initSearchFab(); 

            }
        });

        // This is the code in the docs, but this launches the turn by turn navigation inside this activity
        // and this is not what I need

/*        fabstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                boolean simulateRoute = false;
                NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
                        .directionsRoute(route)
                        .shouldSimulateRoute(simulateRoute)
                        .build();
                // Call this method with Context from within an Activity
                NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(MainActivity.this, options);

            }
        });*/

        fabstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Before_Go.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                // Here is where I want to go to a new activity, inside this activity have a button to
                // launch the "NavigationLauncher.startNavigation"
            }
        });


    }
  
    private static class StyleCycle {
        private static final String[] STYLES = new String[] {
                Style.MAPBOX_STREETS,
                Style.OUTDOORS,
                Style.LIGHT,
                Style.DARK,
                //Style.SATELLITE_STREETS,
                Style.TRAFFIC_DAY,
                Style.TRAFFIC_NIGHT
        };

        private int index;

        private String getNextStyle() {
            index++;
            if (index == STYLES.length) {
                index = 0;
            }
            return getStyle();
        }

        private String getStyle() {
            return STYLES[index];
        }
    }

    private void initSearchFab() {

        findViewById(R.id.search).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder()
                        .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
                        .placeOptions(PlaceOptions.builder()
                                .backgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEEEE"))
                                .limit(10)
                                //.addInjectedFeature(home)
                                //.addInjectedFeature(work)
                                .build(PlaceOptions.MODE_CARDS))
                        .build(MainActivity.this);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE);

            }

        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
    private void initializeLocationComponent(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle) {

        // Check if permissions are enabled and if not request
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {

            locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();
            // Set the LocationComponent activation options
            LocationComponentActivationOptions locationComponentActivationOptions =
                    LocationComponentActivationOptions.builder(this, loadedMapStyle)
                            .useDefaultLocationEngine(false)
                            .build();


            // Activate with the LocationComponentActivationOptions object
            locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(locationComponentActivationOptions);
            locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);
            locationComponent.setRenderMode(RenderMode.NORMAL);
            locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);
            //locationComponent.zoomWhileTracking(10d);

            initLocationEngine();

        } else {

            permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE) {

            // Retrieve selected location's CarmenFeature
            selectedCarmenFeature = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(data);
            search.setText(selectedCarmenFeature.placeName());

            // Create a new FeatureCollection and add a new Feature to it using selectedCarmenFeature above.
            // Then retrieve and update the source designated for showing a selected location's symbol layer icon

            if (mapboxMap != null) {
                Style style = mapboxMap.getStyle();
                if (style != null) {
                    GeoJsonSource source = style.getSourceAs(geojsonSourceLayerId);
                    if (source != null) {
                        source.setGeoJson(FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(
                                new Feature[] {Feature.fromJson(selectedCarmenFeature.toJson())}));
                    }

                    // Move map camera to the selected location
                    mapboxMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(
                            new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                    .target(new LatLng(((Point) selectedCarmenFeature.geometry()).latitude(),
                                            ((Point) selectedCarmenFeature.geometry()).longitude()))
                                    .zoom(14)
                                    .build()), 4000);

                }
            }
        }
    }  

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void vibrate() {
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        if (vibrator == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(ONE_HUNDRED_MILLISECONDS, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
        } else {
            vibrator.vibrate(ONE_HUNDRED_MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set up the LocationEngine and the parameters for querying the device's location
     */
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void initLocationEngine() {
        locationEngine = LocationEngineProvider.getBestLocationEngine(this);

        LocationEngineRequest request = new LocationEngineRequest.Builder(DEFAULT_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS)
                .setPriority(LocationEngineRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setMaxWaitTime(DEFAULT_MAX_WAIT_TIME).build();

        locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates(request, callback, getMainLooper());
        locationEngine.getLastLocation(callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.user_location_permission_explanation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
        if (granted) {
            if (mapboxMap.getStyle() != null) {
                initializeLocationComponent(mapboxMap.getStyle());
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.user_location_permission_not_granted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    private static class MainActivityLocationCallback
            implements LocationEngineCallback<LocationEngineResult> {

        private final WeakReference<MainActivity> activityWeakReference;

        MainActivityLocationCallback(MainActivity activity) {
            this.activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LocationEngineResult result) {
            MainActivity activity = activityWeakReference.get();
            if (activity != null) {
                Location location = result.getLastLocation();
                if (location == null) {
                    return;
                }
                if (activity.mapboxMap != null && result.getLastLocation() != null) {
                    activity.mapboxMap.getLocationComponent().forceLocationUpdate(result.getLastLocation());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            Timber.d(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
            MainActivity activity = activityWeakReference.get();
            if (activity != null) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, exception.getLocalizedMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds the GeoJSON source to the map
     */
    private void setUpSource(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle) {
        loadedMapStyle.addSource(new GeoJsonSource(geojsonSourceLayerId));
    }

    /**
     * Setup a layer with maki icons, eg. west coast city.
     */
    private void setupLayer(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle) {
        loadedMapStyle.addLayer(new SymbolLayer("SYMBOL_LAYER_ID", geojsonSourceLayerId).withProperties(
                iconImage(symbolIconId),
                iconOffset(new Float[] {0f, -8f})
        ));


    }

    // This method will remove the destination icon
    private void toggleLayer() {
        mapboxMap.getStyle(new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
            @Override
            public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                layer = style.getLayer("SYMBOL_LAYER_ID");
                if (layer != null) {
                    if (VISIBLE.equals(layer.getVisibility().getValue())) {
                        layer.setProperties(visibility(NONE));
                    } else {
                        layer.setProperties(visibility(VISIBLE));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }


    // Add the mapView lifecycle to the activity's lifecycle methods
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();

        if (mapRoute != null) {
            mapRoute.onStart();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();

        if (mapRoute != null) {
            mapRoute.onStop();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Before_Go - this is the activity where i want to click the button and launch the navigationlauncher

public class Before_Go extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button btnGo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_before__go);

    btnGo=findViewById(R.id.btnGo);

    btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent btnGo = new Intent(Before_Go.this, Go.class);
            startActivity(btnGo);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
    GoActivity, this is where the navigation launcher needs to launch after the button click in the Before_Go activity
    
    public class Go extends AppCompatActivity implements OnNavigationReadyCallback,
            NavigationListener {
    
        private NavigationView navigationView;
        private DirectionsRoute route;
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_NoActionBar);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_go);
            navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationViewB);
            navigationView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
        }
            /*fabstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        boolean simulateRoute = false;
                        NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
                                .directionsRoute(route)
                                .shouldSimulateRoute(simulateRoute)
                                .build();
                        // Call this method with Context from within an Activity
                        NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(MainActivity.this, options);
    
                    }
                });*/
    
        @Override
        public void onNavigationReady(boolean isRunning) {
            MapboxNavigationOptions.Builder navigationOptions = MapboxNavigationOptions.builder();
            NavigationViewOptions.Builder options = NavigationViewOptions.builder();
            options.navigationListener(this);
            extractRoute(options);
            extractConfiguration(options);
            options.navigationOptions(navigationOptions.build());
            //options.navigationOptions(new MapboxNavigationOptions.Builder().build());
            launchNavigationWithRoute();
            //navigationView.startNavigation(options.build());
            navigationView.initialize(this);
    
    /*MapboxNavigationOptions.Builder navigationOptions = MapboxNavigationOptions.builder();
            NavigationViewOptions.Builder options = NavigationViewOptions.builder();
            options.navigationListener(this);
    
            extractRoute(options);
    
            options.navigationOptions(navigationOptions.build());
            //navigationView = NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(options.build());
            navigationView.startNavigation(options.build());
            initialize();*/
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCancelNavigation() {
            // Navigation canceled, finish the activity
            showCustomCancel();
            finishNavigation();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onNavigationFinished() {
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onNavigationRunning() {
    
        }
    
        private void launchNavigationWithRoute() {
            if (route != null) {
                NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(this, route);
            }
        }
    
        private void extractRoute(NavigationViewOptions.Builder options) {
            route = NavigationLauncher.extractRoute(this);
            options.directionsRoute(route);
        }
    
        private void extractConfiguration(NavigationViewOptions.Builder options) {
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            options.shouldSimulateRoute(preferences.getBoolean(NavigationConstants.NAVIGATION_VIEW_SIMULATE_ROUTE, false));
    
    
        }
    
        private void finishNavigation() {
            NavigationLauncher.cleanUpPreferences(this);
            finish();
        }
    
        private void showCustomCancel(){
            ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            View dialogView2 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_logout, viewGroup, false);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setView(dialogView2);
            AlertDialog alertDialog2 = builder.create();
            Button buttonNo = dialogView2.findViewById(R.id.buttonNo);
            Button buttonYes = dialogView2.findViewById(R.id.buttonYes);
    
            buttonYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (alertDialog2 != null && alertDialog2.isShowing()) {
                        alertDialog2.dismiss();
                    }
                    Intent intentCancelTrip_Yes = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intentCancelTrip_Yes);
                    finish();
                    navigationView.stopNavigation();
                }
            });
    
            buttonNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (alertDialog2 != null && alertDialog2.isShowing()) {
                        alertDialog2.dismiss();
    
                    }
                    navigationView.onResume();
    
                }
            });
    
    
            alertDialog2.show();
    
    
        }
    
    /*    private void initialize() {
            Parcelable position = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NavigationConstants.NAVIGATION_VIEW_INITIAL_MAP_POSITION);
            if (position != null) {
                navigationView.initialize(this, (CameraPosition) position);
            } else {
                navigationView.initialize(this);
            }
        }*/
    
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            navigationView.onStart();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            navigationView.onResume();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onLowMemory() {
            super.onLowMemory();
            navigationView.onLowMemory();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // If the navigation view didn't need to do anything, call super
            if (!navigationView.onBackPressed()) {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            navigationView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            navigationView.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            navigationView.onPause();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            navigationView.onStop();
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            navigationView.onDestroy();
        }
    }

NavigationLauncher class i am using to try initiate the navigation inside the Go activity

public class NavigationLauncher {


    public static void startNavigation(Activity activity, DirectionsRoute route) {

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(NavigationConstants.NAVIGATION_VIEW_ROUTE_KEY, new Gson().toJson(route));

        //editor.putString(NavigationConstants.NAVIGATION_VIEW_AWS_POOL_ID, awsPoolId);
        //editor.putBoolean(NavigationConstants.NAVIGATION_VIEW_SIMULATE_ROUTE, simulateRoute);
        editor.apply();

        Intent navigationActivity = new Intent(activity, Go.class);
        activity.startActivity(navigationActivity);

    }

   /* public static void startNavigation(Activity activity, NavigationLauncherOptions options){

           SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        storeDirectionsRouteValue(options, editor);
        storeConfiguration(options, editor);
        editor.apply();


        Intent navigationActivity = new Intent(activity, Go.class);
        storeInitialMapPosition(options, navigationActivity);
        activity.startActivity(navigationActivity);

    }*/

    private static void storeConfiguration(NavigationLauncherOptions options, SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
        editor.putBoolean(NavigationConstants.NAVIGATION_VIEW_SIMULATE_ROUTE, options.shouldSimulateRoute());
    }

    private static void storeDirectionsRouteValue(NavigationLauncherOptions options, SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
        editor.putString(NavigationConstants.NAVIGATION_VIEW_ROUTE_KEY, options.directionsRoute().toJson());

        /*if (options.directionsRoute() != null) {
            storeDirectionsRouteValue(options, editor);
        }
         else {
            throw new RuntimeException("A valid DirectionsRoute or origin and "
                    + "destination must be provided in NavigationViewOptions");
        }*/
    }

    static DirectionsRoute extractRoute(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String directionsRouteJson = preferences.getString(NavigationConstants.NAVIGATION_VIEW_ROUTE_KEY, "");
        return DirectionsRoute.fromJson(directionsRouteJson);
    }

    static void cleanUpPreferences(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor
                .remove(NavigationConstants.NAVIGATION_VIEW_ROUTE_KEY)
                .remove(NavigationConstants.NAVIGATION_VIEW_SIMULATE_ROUTE)
                .apply();
    }

    private static void  storeInitialMapPosition(NavigationLauncherOptions options, Intent navigationActivity) {
        if (options.initialMapCameraPosition() != null) {
            navigationActivity.putExtra(
                    NavigationConstants.NAVIGATION_VIEW_INITIAL_MAP_POSITION, options.initialMapCameraPosition()
            );
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the application crashes once the activity "Go.java" is launched.

The problem appears to be that you are not instantiating the Mapbox object in this activity. You are doing it correclty in your "mainactivity.java" however you are missing it in "go.java". Make sure to have the line  `Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token));` also in your "go.java" activity before calling `setContentView()`

```js
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token));

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: Hi Moritz, thanks for taking the time to go through the code. I've added your suggestion, however, it's not working. With your suggestion and without your suggestion, the navigationview loads but no directions/route or map populate, it's just a blank screen with the navigation view style and the cancel button in the bottom right.